# Is alleged claim that Chaitanya Mahaprabhu was from a Shakta family have any basis in authentic biographies?

Tags: gaudiya-vaishnavism, chaitanya, shaktism

From Chaitanya Charitamrita:

> śrīhaṭṭa-nivāsī śrī-upendra-miśra-nāma vaiṣṇava, paṇḍita, dhanī,
>   sad-guṇa-pradhāna
>
> CC 1.13.56: There was also Śrī Upendra Miśra, a resident of the
>   district of Śrīhaṭṭa. He was a great devotee of Lord Viṣṇu, a learned
>   scholar, a rich man and a reservoir of all good qualities.
>
> sapta miśra tāṅra putra — sapta ṛṣīśvara
>   kaṁsāri, paramānanda, padmanābha, sarveśvara
>   jagannātha, janārdana, trailokyanātha
>   nadīyāte gaṅgā-vāsa kaila jagannātha
>
> CC 1.13.57-58: Upendra Miśra had seven sons, who were all saintly and most influential: (1) Kaṁsāri, (2) Paramānanda, (3) Padmanābha, (4) Sarveśvara, (5) Jagannātha, (6) Janārdana and (7) Trailokyanātha. Jagannātha Miśra, the fifth son, decided to reside on the bank of the Ganges at Nadia.
>
> jagannātha miśravara — padavī ‘purandara’
>   nanda-vasudeva-rūpa sadguṇa-sāgara
>
> CC 1.13.59: Jagannātha Miśra was designated as Purandara. Exactly like Nanda Mahārāja and Vasudeva, he was an ocean of all good qualities.
>
> tāṅra patnī ‘śacī’-nāma, pativratā satī
>   yāṅra pitā ‘nīlāmbara’ nāma cakravartī
>
> CC 1.13.60: His wife, Śrīmatī Śacīdevī, was a chaste woman highly devoted to her husband. Śacīdevī’s father’s name was Nīlāmbara, and his surname was Cakravartī.
>
> miśra — vaiṣṇava, śānta, alampaṭa, śuddha, dānta,
>   dhana-bhoge nāhi abhimāna
>   putrera prabhāve yata, dhana āsi’ mile, tata,
>   viṣṇu-prīte dvije dena dāna
>
> CC 1.13.120: Jagannātha Miśra was an ideal Vaiṣṇava. He was peaceful, restrained in sense gratification, pure and controlled. Therefore he had no desire to enjoy material opulence. Whatever money came because of the influence of his transcendental son, he gave it in charity to the brāhmaṇas for the satisfaction of Viṣṇu.

From Chaitanya Bhagavata:

> tanna patni saci-nama maha-pati-vrata
>   murti-mati visnu-bhakti sei jagan-mata//CB, Adi 2.139//
>
> TRANSLATION:
>   His wife was the most chaste Sacidevi, the universal mother and
>   personification of devotional service to the Supreme Lord.

These show that the grandfather of Chaitanya Mahaprabhu Upendra Misra was also Vaishnava, and pretty much whole family appears Vaishnava.

However, some believe that they are Shaktas, why do they think so? Is it that Chaitanya Mahaprabhu's family was Shaktas few generations before and then started Vaishnava practices from time of his grandfather? I am interested to know from authentic biographies. If any other biography mentions Chaitanya Mahaprabhu's family as Shakta family, how do they resolve contradictions with the above verses?

Comment: u gave sloka nos different from the version accepted by the scholars.However I see no contradiction.Vaishnava means devoted to Vishnu.The brahmins inspite of being Shakta are ever devotees of Vishnu.But they were not FORMAL Vaishnavas because

Comment: 1.There is NO nention of tilaka and kanthimala. 2.They worshipped salgram shila (same chapter) and not idol of Krishna, which is normal for brahmins.3.Sri Chaitanyadeva gifted a own handwritten punthi of 'Sri Sri Chandi' to His grandfather when He visited Srihatta.No 'formal Vaishnava' family reads and worships Chandi.But that punthi was worshupped till it was stolen.

Comment: 4.Mahaprabhu's devotion to Devi is also noteworthy which is not seen in Vaishnava families

Comment: @Pratimaputra there is no need to taunt every time Kali yuga etc... :). My point was both Chaitanya Mangala and   Nabadwipa mahatmya, even many events in Cb and Cc are cooked up a/c to those who don't believe in mahaprabhu. That extensive discussion is not appropriate for this site. I am happy to accept well researched answer if verses from authentic biographies are cited... I am more into Gaudiya Vaishnava theology than hagiographies.

Comment: You changed the title.So please provide a list of AUTHENTIC BIOGRAPHIES.